# Bypass DNS Server lookup by using /etc/hosts when using a dynamic IP address

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, hosts, embedded-linux, dns-lookup

It is my understanding that the need to query external DNS servers for commonly accessed names can be reduced if those commonly accessed names are present in /etc/hosts.

Now, I have a situation where in I have an Embedded Linux box with a dynamic IP address. Let's assume this dynamic IP address is currently 206.190.36.105.

Here are the contents of my /etc/hosts file:

```
[root@zop]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.0.1     mydevice
173.194.33.18   somesite.com
```

However when I run tcpdump and ping somesite.com, I still see that somesite.com is being resolved via DNS lookup.

```
17:28:48.330535 IP 206.190.36.105 > somesite.com: ICMP echo request, id 14880, seq 0, length 64
17:28:48.333465 IP 206.190.36.105.57201 > resolver1.opendns.com.domain: 2+ PTR? 204.220.167.10.in-addr.arpa. (45)
17:28:49.312286 IP somesite.com > 206.190.36.105: ICMP echo reply, id 14880, seq 0, length 64
17:28:49.335601 IP 206.190.36.105 > somesite.com: ICMP echo request, id 14880, seq 1, length 64
17:28:49.366973 IP resolver1.opendns.com.domain > 206.190.36.105.57201: 2* 0/1/0 (104)
17:28:49.368286 IP 206.190.36.105.59381 > resolver1.opendns.com.domain: 3+ PTR? 204.220.167.10.in-addr.arpa. (45)
17:28:49.664215 IP somesite.com > 206.190.36.105: ICMP echo reply, id 14880, seq 1, length 64
17:28:49.742004 IP resolver1.opendns.com.domain > 206.190.36.105.59381: 3* 0/1/0 (104)
17:28:49.743194 IP 206.190.36.105.57388 > resolver1.opendns.com.domain: 4+ PTR? 204.220.167.10.in-addr.arpa. (45)
17:28:50.038848 IP resolver1.opendns.com.domain > 206.190.36.105.57388: 4* 0/1/0 (104)
17:28:50.040069 IP 206.190.36.105.53513 > resolver1.opendns.com.domain: 5+ PTR? 204.220.167.10.in-addr.arpa. (45)
17:28:50.335815 IP resolver1.opendns.com.domain > 206.190.36.105.53513: 5* 0/1/0 (104)
17:28:50.337036 IP 206.190.36.105.54248 > resolver1.opendns.com.domain: 6+ PTR? 204.220.167.10.in-addr.arpa. (45)
```

If I create an entry for the current IP address of the Linux box in /etc/hosts as in:

```
[root@zop]# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.0.101   mydevice
173.194.33.18   somesite.com
206.190.36.105   whatismyip
```

then tcpdump in tandem with a ping to somesite.com shows that the DNS lookup is now bypassed

```
17:15:35.795013 IP whatismyip > somesite.com: ICMP echo request, id 61212, seq 0, length 64
17:15:36.648193 IP somesite.com > whatismyip: ICMP echo reply, id 61212, seq 0, length 64
17:15:36.809234 IP whatismyip > somesite.com: ICMP echo request, id 61212, seq 1, length 64
17:15:37.164276 IP somesite.com > whatismyip: ICMP echo reply, id 61212, seq 1, length 64
17:15:37.819915 IP whatismyip > somesite.com: ICMP echo request, id 61212, seq 2, length 64
17:15:38.148193 IP somesite.com > whatismyip: ICMP echo reply, id 61212, seq 2, length 64
17:15:38.827728 IP whatismyip > somesite.com: ICMP echo request, id 61212, seq 3, length 64
```

I'm interested in understanding the rationale behind this observed behavior. The Embedded Linux vendor claims that this behavior is normal and expected behavior - but rationally, shouldn't the DNS lookup be bypassed if only the destination IP address is not in the /etc/hosts file?

Comment: What does `/etc/resolv.conf` look like? Does it contain `127.0.0.1`? If there are multiple IPs, are their gateways on separate interfaces?

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf does not contain 127.0.0.1 - could that be the reason that DNS lookups are bypassed? /etc/resolv.conf contains openDNS server IP addresses as in "nameserver 208.67.222.222".  
I'm not sure I understand your question on multiple IPs and gateways on separate interfaces. Could you elaborate please? @AndrewB

Comment: You shouldn't have `127.0.0.1` in that file unless the machine is running a DNS server, so it's good that you don't have it. My other question was whether or not you had multiple `nameserver` lines, with each taking routes on different interfaces. If you're using OpenDNS that won't be the case.

Comment: @AndrewB There are currently three nameserver entries, all point to 208.67.222.222

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing forward DNS lookups with reverse DNS lookups.

Forward DNS lookups are going from a name to an IP address. If you look at the DNS packets in your first tcpdump, you'll see `PTR?` (pointer request), which is a request to translate an IP to a name.

`z.y.x.w.in-addr.arpa` is the IP being requested in reverse lookup notation. If you reverse that order, you get w.x.y.z, the IP address it's attempting to look up.

I suspect `tcpdump` is the source of the reverse lookup requests, not `ping`, as it has no need to perform a reverse lookup on your IP. When you add your IP to `/etc/hosts`, `tcpdump` no longer has a need to perform a reverse lookup on your IP, as your resolver library can locate it without performing DNS queries.

It's usually a good idea to run `tcpdump` with the `-n` option in order to avoid these lookups. They're usually not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for elucidating re: reverse/forward lookups. Page 395 of Practical UNIX and Internet Security by Simson Garfinkel, Gene Spafford, Alan Schwartz, 3rd Ed confirms your suspicion about tcpdump being the source of the reverse lookups.

Answer (score 2):

The order of lookups is usually controlled by `/etc/nsswitch`.  Beware that if you have entries in `/etc/hosts` and that is the first lookup, DNS lookups won't occur.  Make sure the entries are both static and correct.

If `dns` is first, `/etc/hosts` will only be used if dns lookups fail.  If `files` is first, dns is only used if `/etc/hosts` fails.

The `search` and `domain` lines in `/etc/resolv.conf` may cause additional lookups to be tried if the name is not found.  The `ndots` option can be used to indicate who many dots are required to disable use of the `search` and `domain` in searching.

You can use aliases in `/etc/hosts` tied to the first entry in `search` to prevent lookups with additional search domains.

Comment: There is no /etc/nsswitch on this embedded linux system.

Comment: On an embedded system it may be coded into the resolver library.  Knowing the resolver order is important to your desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The DNS requests you see are Reverse requests mapping IP to a domain name:

```
PTR 204.220.167.10.in-addr.arpa.
```

Ping asks for the name of 10.167.220.204 (presumably the IP of your client?). I didn't see any forward requests (resolving somesite.com to an IP address) in your `tcpdump` output.

Now back to your original intent - which I assume is to reduce the network traffic. If you run `nscd` (Name Services Caching Daemon) you will generally see only one DNS request for each hostname and the `nscd` daemon will than cache it for you. That's a lot better option than keeping `/etc/hosts` up to date with network changes and renumberings.